# Dialogflow (API.AI) get unique Device ID

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es, google-assist-api

Is there a posibility to get a unique Device ID from a Google Home Device?
I have not found that in the Json Request to webhook. There is a User ID but i need to find out which Device is used for the request.

Comment: Here, https://discuss.api.ai/t/how-to-get-unique-id-for-google-home-device/9253

Comment: i found that earlier but unfortunally there is no "unique_device_id" in the json..

Comment: you might be using a Google Assistant or a simulator.Using Google Assistant and the simulator the field isn’t set as indicated in the comment section.

Comment: I tried it with two devices. Neither the Google Home nor the Google Home mini sent the id

Comment: the unique_device_id is removed.. - https://discuss.api.ai/t/did-something-happen-to-originalrequest-data-device/12958/2

Comment: they might be moving towards account-linking then. Well, instead of device_id, user_id should matter!

Comment: the problem is that i need to find out the device (or its name). Linking each device to a seperate account doesn't work because if the voice is not matched to the accound-owners voice, the user_id is random and last only one conversation

Comment: every account linking will be representing with some user_id  on which you have linked your account. Moreover, save the user_id obtained from the system used for account linking to the dynamoDB and get back the id everytime you have a conversation with the echo.

Comment: My action is designed so that it can be used by certain devices and provides information based on the device used for the request. For example, there is a device on every table and the waiter needs to know where to go if necessary.

Comment: The only method you can use here is making out an account for every table and authenticating them if the numbers of tables are not high enough or the other approach will be asking the guest to tell the table number after/before making an order.

Comment: "When no voice matches: If a registered user's voice isn't recognized by the device or no registered voice exists, then a different ID is used that is unique for just that conversation." - https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info
Thats why the user id won't work for my action

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I have a similar use-case where I need to know which device triggered the fulfillment so I know the room it is in, but I can't seem to receive that in the request.

Comment: I surrendered. In case that there is a way today, I do not think that will be possible in the near future.